# How can I use COUNT() result in RANK

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query for 'SQL Server' which 'count()' based on column 'id'.
And I also want to 'RANK' based on the value of COUNT(). But when I try the below query,
I get error sayign 'Invalid column names 'IdCount''

```
SELECT 
[id],
COUNT(*) AS IdCount,
RANK() OVER ( 
   ORDER BY IdCount
) CountRank
  FROM  myTable
  where DATEDIFF(day,[Time],GETDATE()) < 30
  GROUP BY [id]
```

Can you please tell me how can I reference the COUNT() result?

Thank you.

Comment: From the query attempt it looks like you want the one with the lowest count to have the lowest rank, which seems opposite to me, but showing us some data and your desired results will remove any doubts. See [how to MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an expression's alias in a window function at the same scope. Also, I think you want the `RANK()` to be applied from the *highest* count, not the lowest. Finally, you should never apply calculations like `DATEDIFF` against a column. How about:

```
DECLARE @start date = DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());

SELECT id, IdCount,
  CountRank = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IdCount DESC)
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.myTable
    WHERE [Time] >= @start
    GROUP BY id
) AS x;
```